# Google ScriptDB: How to retrieve a Key Value Pair using a variable?

Tags: database, google-apps-script, database-scripts

I am using Google UI Apps and ScriptDB, and I have a map object similar to this:

```
myMapObject = {record_id: projectA,
               apple : 316,
               orange : 956,
               banana : 536}
```

I am wondering how to use a variable in a query to retrieve the key value pair data. Or, is it even possible? For example:

```
var userChoice = e.parameter.choice;
var userLimit = e.parameter.limit;
var result = db.query({userChoice : db.greaterThan(userLimit)})
```

Now, I know using a variable works for the conditional statement, db.greaterThan(userLimit). However, I haven't been able to use a varriable (i.e. "userChoice") in the way I have written it for the key value.

Note, that this is only a simplified example of the code and I am not looking for a way to restruction the map object. What I would like to know is, if it is possible to use a varriable in some way to perform the query. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable as property, but it's a different syntax. Like this:

```js
var query = {};
query[userChoice] = db.greaterThan(userLimit);
//edit as requested in the comment
query.record_id = 'projectA'; //or query['record_id'] = ...
var result = db.query(query);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am totally new to scripting. I haven't your answer yet but will soon. However, to expand on your answer if I were to include an additional key value in the query, such as record_id, what would be the combined syntax?

Comment: Added an example for you. This syntax does not allow you to have everything in a single line as you as can do with "fixed" property names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use a variable to perform a query. Remember, though: The key value must be present in the object you're querying. In your example, `userChoice` is not a property of `myMapObject`, so it won't match.

Here's an example related to those in the [ScriptDb Service Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/). The `findOlderThan()` function accepts a parameter `age` which is used in a query of `people` objects. Those `people` objects have 4 properties, `type`, `name`, `age`, and `single`. Therefore, a query that expects to extract `people` must reference one or more of those properties. Since ScriptDb is agnostic about the objects you store in it, we use of the `type` property as a convention to identify object types - and we do that in every query. We could just query for `age`, but that could also find objects that aren't `people`, which we aren't interested in.

```
function findOlderThan( age ) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var people = [];  // array to hold results

  // Find people with an age greater than given value.
  var results = db.query({
    type: 'person',
    age: db.greaterThan(age)
  });
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var item = results.next();
    people.push(item);
  }
  return people;
}

function test_findOlderThan() {
  deleteAll(); // from developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/patterns#delete_all_items_in_the_database
  loadDb();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(findOlderThan(20))); // 3 results
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(findOlderThan(25))); // 2 results
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(findOlderThan(50))); // 1 result
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(findOlderThan(100))); // no result
}

function loadDb() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var item = db.save({
    type: 'person',
    name: 'fred',
    town: 'Shelbyville',
    age: 25,
    single: true
  });
  item = db.save({
    type: 'person',
    name: 'joe',
    town: 'Springfield',
    age: 45,
    single: false
  });
  item = db.save({
    type: 'person',
    name: 'sam',
    town: 'Springfield',
    age: 90,
    single: true
  });
}
```